# Trigger $scope.$watch when static attribute changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element with a custom directive on it as so.

```
<div my-directive data-progress="0"></div>
```

my-directive is as follows.

```
return {

    scope: {
        progress: '@'
    }

    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes){

        $scope.$watch('progress', function(newVal){
           // do stuff with newVal
        })

    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when data-progress on the element is changed by an external source (such as jQuery) it never triggers the watch. I also tried using $attributes.$observe but that doesn't get triggered wither. This is a custom progress bar directive so an external source will be updating the data-progress and I need to the watch to fire so I can properly update the progress bar.

Comment: That is not possible with angular.  Angular has no way to know that the attribute has changed outside of a digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use observe since you specified it as an attribute (by using @),

```
$attributes.$observe("progress", function(newVal){

});
```

Here's the documentation on it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe

Comment: As noted before I tried that and it will only fire once when the directive is loaded. After that it doesn't fire when the value is changed. The only time it works is if I change the value from with in the directive which I'm not trying to do.